# Bash arrays and negative subscripts, yes or no?

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, unix, gnu

The [GNU bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) tells me

> An indexed array is created automatically if any variable is assigned
>   to using the syntax
>
> ```
> name[subscript]=value
> ```
>
> The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must
>   evaluate to a number. If subscript evaluates to a number less than
>   zero, it is used as an offset from one greater than the array’s
>   maximum index (so a subcript of -1 refers to the last element of the
>   array).

So I figure I will give it a try and get the following result:

```
$ muh=(1 4 'a' 'bleh' 2)
$ echo $muh
1
$ echo ${muh[*]}
1 4 a bleh 2    # so far so good so now I'll try a negative ...
$ echo ${muh[-1]}
-bash: muh: bad array subscript  # didn't go as planned!
```

Did I do something wrong, or is the website wrong, or is gnu bash that different from the bash I am running under CentOS?  Thanks!

Comment: it's version-specific. Worked under bash 4.2 but failed under 3.2 for me

Comment: @ravoori:  Ah! And I have 3.2!  Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just want the last element

```
$ echo ${muh[*]: -1}
2
```

If you want next to last element

```
$ echo ${muh[*]: -2:1}
bleh
```

Comment: @bob.sacamento that's because `${parameter:-word}` is a different expansion that means *substitute `word` if `parameter` is unset or null.*

Comment: Note that `${muh[*]: -2}` gives you the last 2 elements, not the second-to-last element. (I haven't checked the manual yet to see where the [deleted] that syntax comes from.

Comment: `${muh[*]: -2}` is an example of Substring Expansion, which on arrays acts like slicing.

Comment: @kojiro Allow me to offer a heartfelt random thank you from a random person on the internet! I never would have figured out that I needed a space to index backwards.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Greg Wooledge's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061), (which links to the bash changelog) the negative index syntax was added to bash in version 4.2 alpha.

Answer (score 7):

Bash beore 4.2 (like the default one on Macs these days) doesn't support negative subscripts. Apart from the "substring expansion" used in the accepted answer, a possibly cleaner workaround is to count the desired index from the array start within the brackets:

```sh
$ array=(one two three)
$ echo "${array[${#array[@]}-1]}"
three
```

With this approach, you can pack other parameter expansion operations into the term, e.g. "remove matching prefix pattern" `th`:

```
$ echo "${array[${#array[@]}-1]#th}"
ree
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do `man bash` the section on arrays does not list this behavior.  It might be something new (gnu?) in bash.

Fails for me in CentOS 6.3 (bash 4.1.2)

Answer (score 3):

The negative subscript works perfectly fine for me on my computer with Ubuntu 14.04 / GNU bash version 4.3.11(1) however it returns:

```
line 46: [-1]: bad array subscript
```

When I try to run the same script on 4.2.46(1). I