# Bad array subscript

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm relatively new to Shell and I've been trying to use arrays in Shell and it's not working well. I'm trying to write a script to suspend OpenVZ containers should they hit a certain bandwidth threshold over a period of time.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Thresholds are in bytes per second and count1 must > count2
LOGDIR="/var/log/outbound_ddos"
SECS=10
THRESHOLD1=65536000
COUNT1=10
THRESHOLD2=117964800
COUNT2=2

while [ 1 ]
do
    for veid in $(/usr/sbin/vzlist -o veid -H)
    do      
        # Create the log file if it doesn't already exist
        if ! test -e $LOGDIR/$veid.log; then
            touch $LOGDIR/$veid.log
        fi

        # Parse out the inbound/outbound traffic and assign them to the corresponding variables     
        eval $(/usr/sbin/vzctl exec $veid "grep venet0 /proc/net/dev"  |  \
            awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{printf"CTOUT=%s\n", $9}')

        # Print the output and a timestamp to a log file
        echo $(date +%s) $CTOUT >> $LOGDIR/$veid.log

        # Read last 10 entries into arrays
        i=0
        tail $LOGDIR/$veid.log | while read time byte
        do
            times[$i]=time; bytes[$i]=byte
            let i++
        done

        # Sanity checks and calculations
        for (( i=0; i<COUNT1; i++ ))
        do
            # Sanity check on the time
            if (( times[$i] > times[$i - 1] + $SECS + 10 ))
                then continue
            fi

            # Calculate differences
            let "diff[$i] = bytes[$i+1] - bytes[$i]"
        done

        # Work out thresholds and suspend where necessary
        # Higher threshold first
        t2=0
                for (( i=COUNT1-1; i>=0; i-- ))
                do
                        if [ ! diff[$i] ]
                                then continue
                                else
                                        if (( bytes[$i] < THRESHOLD1 * SECS + bytes[$i-1] + 1 ))
                                                then continue
                        else let t2++
                                        fi
                        fi
                done
        #Lower threshold last
        t1=0
        for (( i=COUNT1-1; i>=0; i-- ))
        do
            if [ ! diff[$i] ]
                then continue
                else
                    if (( bytes[$i] < THRESHOLD1 * SECS + bytes[$i-1] + 1 ))
                        then continue
                        else let t1++
                    fi
            fi
        done

        # Suspend where necessary
        if (( ($t2 >= $COUNT2) || ($t1 >= $COUNT1) ))
            then vzctl stop veid
        fi
    done
    sleep $SECS
done
```

And the errors:

```
script.sh: line 38: times: bad array subscript
script.sh: line 54: bytes: bad array subscript
script.sh: line 67: bytes: bad array subscript
```

I've tried several variations of the array subscript but I can't seem to get rid of those errors.

Comment: You're missing quite a few `$` all over the place.  e.g. should be `times[$i]` for instance.

Comment: Apologies, I've amended the post. Same errors though.

Comment: @Mat actually the `$` sign is not required inside an array subscript.

Comment: @kojiro: hum, indeed seems to work. Confusing though.

Comment: @Mat It's a context thing. Array subscripts are arithmetic context, same as `(( ))` arithmetic expressions. So OP could write `times[i]=time; bytes[i++]=byte` on line 30.

Comment: @kojiro: ok, good to know. `times[i]=$time; bytes[i++]=$byte` though surely.

Comment: +1 for interesting question. Won't have time to dig in on this today. Good luck!

Comment: The while loop where you set `times` and `bytes` is executed in a subshell because of the pipeline. Those changes won't be visible in the remainder of your script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So on line 38,

```
if (( times[$i] > times[$i - 1] + $SECS + 10 ))
```

would refer to `times[-1]` once during the iteration. Negative indices are [only very recently part of bash arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110069/418413), so that is most likely why you are getting the error.

Likewise with lines 54 and 67 you're hitting a negative array subscript once. Adjust your loops to avoid `[0 - 1]`.